# Given a multiple-choice survey, test the hypothesis that choice i is more common in the population than choice j

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, multiple-comparisons, survey

I have a survey with m possible choices, only one answer allowed for respondent. Let $n$ be the sample size, and $\tilde{p}_k=\frac{n_k}{n}$, $k=1,\dots m$, the observed frequencies for each choice. Now, with an abuse of notation, Let's denote with $\tilde{p}_1,\dots\tilde{p}_k$ the frequencies sorted from the largest to the smallest (with ties broken randomly). How do I test the hypothesis $p_1\geq p_2$? More in general, how do I test the hypothesis that $p_i\geq p_j,\ i<j$? I think this requires correcting for multiple comparisons, also given that the frequencies to be compared are not prescribed before the survey (we need to sort the frequencies before we can run the test).

**Note**: I'm looking specifically for an answer based on Python, either using a Python package, or explaining the math enough in detail that I can code it myself using `numpy` and `scipy.stats`

Comment: Is m less than n? Is m small, eg, 3 to 5? Why do you want to "break ties" in the observed proportions before further analysis? Are there a lot of small proportions?

Comment: There is a solution here, I believe: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2902578/

Comment: @DavidSmith 1) n is always way bigger than m. Let's say, $n=O(10^3)$ while $m \in [3,6]$. 2) Just a matter of habits. For stuff related to conformal prediction, quantile estimation, etc., it makes a difference whether you break ties randomly or not. I'm ok with not breaking ties if it helps here. 3) You don't know it in advance. I had cases with one proportion really close to "effective zero" ($\approx 1/n$), and the other proportions much bigger. Other cases where they were all of similar size ($\approx 1/m$). Cases where the barplot was skewed Etc.

Comment: @BigBendRegion why don't you write an answer summarizing that paper, if you think it applies here?

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution to comparing multinomial proportions, or are you specifically interested in adjusting for multiple comparisons and the effect of sorting the proportions? If the latter, what is your null hypothesis? Is it that $p_1 = p_2 = \dots = p_k$?

Comment: This is not a legitimate hypothesis, because its formulation is a function of the data!  This can be fixed, but it's unclear how to do it because it's not evident what collection of pairwise comparisons you wish to test.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the insightful comment. Bounty has expired, but hopefully you'll still consider writing an answer. My point is: someone administers a survey, collects results and based on the empirical frequencies, they claim that p_3>p_4>>p_1,p_2 _in the general population_. How can I test this claim? Maybe I should rethink this as estimating a vector of probabilities, and then producing not $m$ separate confidence intervals, but a confidence region, which may or may not include the region of the $m-$dimensional space where $p_3 >p_4$ (for example). Does this make more sense?

Comment: @Eoin my question is as follows. Someone administers a survey, collects results and now they claim, based on the observed frequencies that response 3 has the highest prevalence in the general population, followed closely by response 4, with response 1 and 2 far behind. I want to test the claim that $p_3 > p_4 > p_2 = p_1$. Maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way: I should just think of it as estimating a vector of probabilities. However, I would like to compute a confidence region (not just confidence intervals) so that I could say, with a certain confidence, that, e.g., $p_3 > p_4$

Comment: The problem is that this is a *post hoc* claim.  It is almost surely the case that all the $p_k$ differ in the population, so necessarily *some* ordering exists, and why shouldn't it be the same ordering that appeared in the data? As a practical matter, if $n_3$ greatly exceeds $n_4$ and $n_4$ greatly exceeds $n_2$ *etc.* then this is *likely* the population ordering; but what if (say) $n_4=n_2+1$? Then it's plausible the order of $p_2$ and $p_4$ is reversed. This indicates the importance of narrowing the hypothesis you test and coping with its *post hoc,* exploratory nature.

Comment: @whuber post hoc claims can definitely be made and tested: https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev-statistics-100421-044639. How can we proceed here? Regarding narrowing down the hypothesis (_keeping_ its post-hoc nature), I'm open to suggestions.  Give me some ideas, and if the scope of the original question isn't restricted excessively, I'll modify the question accordingly.

Comment: I am not claiming *post hoc* claims cannot be tested.  The concern raised by your formulation is that with any sizable value of $m,$ the $m!$ hypotheses suggested are too numerous.  Do you really need to test the *one, specific* ordering observed in the data?

Comment: @whuber maybe it could be enough to reject H0: "all frequencies are the same" (like for ANOVA) and then look for significant differences (like Tukey's HSD). Otherwise, if I just produced a confidence interval for each proportion, could I just look at maybe the two largest ones, and check that they don't overlap? What hypothesis would you suggest to test?

Comment: That approach is just the sort of thing that might work.  The reason for Tukey's HSD is that when you check CIs for pairs of proportions, you know you must adjust for multiple testing but you usually don't know how to compensate for the (strong) dependencies among those tests.  The HSD is one way to do both.