# Real-world testing: estimating chance that there's an unknown variable/constraint/relationship

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, failure-rate

I'm working on a hardware product where reliability is paramount. So, one test I've done is to power-cycle units repeatedly, seeing if they properly start up. Result in 10k power-cycles of a group of five units is that there were twenty-eight failures of two different kinds (occurrence of a specific unit failing when cycled was 0.056%, with 0.044% of failure type A, and 0.012% of failure type B). This is bad, and we need to figure out what's going wrong with very little visibility into the startup process.

A possible hint is that the failures were unevenly distributed:

- Two units never failed
- One unit had five failure of type A
- One unit had nine failures of type A
- One unit had eight failures of type A, and six failures of type B

So, I am wondering if the uneven distribution of failures is telling me something, or it's just random luck. My null hypothesis (is that the correct term?) is that each type of failure has a specific chance of occurring on any startup of any unit, with no differences between the units.

How likely is my null hypothesis given my results? Or should I instead ask how likely would I get those results given my null hypothesis?

Comment: Is your hypothesis even relevant? Clearly the failures are not randomly and independently distributed among the units.  The patterns suggest that any unit might have a tendency to suffer failures of type A or type B; and once one failure of a given type is observed, other failures of that type inevitably follow.   More detailed data, such as time between failures, might provide more insight.  Regardless, what you can conclude by studying just five units is limited, so make the most of the information you have rather than performing formal hypthesis tests.

Comment: @whuber My instinct agrees with you, but I'd love to have some formal backing for it. And, with that understanding under my belt, I could evaluate alternative explanations, which would be very helpful.

Comment: Formal backing for which assertion?  There's a fundamental problem with your situation: you have formulated your hypothesis as a reaction to observing a pattern in the data.  That makes standard tests inapplicable.  But *informally* you can point out that just about any reasonable hypothesis about independent uniform distributions of 28 failure events among five units would imply each unit would have observed at least one failure.

Comment: I know that sifting data for unexpected correlations can be fraught (see https://xkcd.com/882/), but is it always a bad idea? Or can it be a good idea, but difficult for formalize? (And, BTW, thanks for the dialog.)

Comment: User DeltaIV, in a comment at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/635600/given-a-multiple-choice-survey-test-the-hypothesis-that-choice-i-is-more-common?noredirect=1#comment1189760_635600, provides a link to an article that discusses this issue and offers three constructive approaches to *post hoc* testing.

Comment: Great reference: thanks. If you think that would be a useful answer, post it and I'll accept it. On the other hand, if you don't think this question could be usefully answered on this stack, let me know and I'll delete it (no reason to add noise to the system). Again, thanks.

Comment: Different formulations of a common underlying question do not need to be considered "noise."  Often they help people find answers when searching.